# NDK OpenSL ES, seamless looping sounds using URI (non buffer) player

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, native-code, opensl

In an effort to get a seamless loop using OpenSL ES's URI player, I tried running the code, taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094377/android-how-to-change-playback-rate-of-music-using-opensl-es/16745755#16745755) question (which queries the length of the audio):

```
SLmillisecond msec;
result = (*fdPlayerPlay)->GetDuration(fdPlayerPlay, &msec);
assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "NDK_debug_tag: ", "fdPlayerPlay GetDuration msec: %d", (int)msec);
```

I get -1 as a result, no matter what.

I can't seem to get anything other than whole file looping working. When I set the loop:

```
// enable whole file looping
result = (*uriPlayerSeek)->SetLoop(uriPlayerSeek, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, 0, 200);
assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
```

And then query the loop points:

```
    SLboolean b;
    SLmillisecond start;
    SLmillisecond end;

    result = (*uriPlayerSeek)->GetLoop(uriPlayerSeek, &b, &start, &end);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "NDK_debug_tag: ", "start: %d end: %d", (int)start, (int)end);
```

I get "start: 0 end: -1", and the file loops from start to finish, instead of just looping a small section (which is what I'm after). The documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519357/supported-opensl-es-features-in-android) only mentions whole file looping:

> Seek
>
> SetLoop enables whole file looping. The startPos parameter should be
> zero and the endPos parameter should be SL_TIME_UNKNOWN.

But it doesn't specifically say that looping part of a file is unsupported. Has anyone had any success with this? Or can verify that this feature is not supported by the OpenSL ES Android implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works for streams, I have not tested it but you might have to buffer in the entire sound data to do duration selections.

The -1 you get is SL_TIME_UNKNOWN (0xFFFFFFFF unsigned), the duration of the stream is unknown. If you just need the duration of the file it should exist in the header somewhere.